# AWS S3 Dynamic HTTP Referer policy with N domains

Tags: amazon-s3, policy, http-referer, whitelist, bucket

Implementing an application where S3 images can only be hotlinked by a list of whitelisted domains.

For a simple case, I can create a Referer Policy with a static list of domains such as:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to have this list be dynamically generated from the DB via a scripting language, and then posted to the AWS via the API SDK.

This could be done by generating a dynamic JSON string for:

```
["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]
```

Is this the best of doing this? I couldn't find any documentation regarding this, but I would imagine there is a limit for the amount of string matches in the StringLike condition?

Would it be better to create an individual StringLike entry inside Condition, one for each domain?

I could potentially have 10000's of domains to white list, so trying to find the best way of scaling this.

Comment: The entire bucket policy is [limited to 20KB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-language-overview.html) so this is probably the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the length limitation in S3's policy framework, this solution was not used.